# Unpack nested list for arguments to map()

Tags: python, list, arguments, map-function, argument-unpacking

I'm sure there's a way of doing this, but I haven't been able to find it. Say I have:

```
foo = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
]

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
```

Then how can I use `map(add, foo)` such that it passes `num1=1`, `num2=2` for the first iteration, i.e., it does `add(1, 2)`, then `add(3, 4)` for the second, etc.?

- Trying `map(add, foo)` obviously does `add([1, 2], #nothing)` for the first iteration
- Trying `map(add, *foo)` does `add(1, 3, 5)` for the first iteration

I want something like `map(add, foo)` to do `add(1, 2)` on the first iteration.

Expected output: `[3, 7, 11]`

Comment: can you check your question as the answers and what you say you want as expected output are not the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.starmap(add, foo))
[3, 7, 11]
```

This unpacks each argument `[a, b]` from the list `foo` for you, passing them to the function `add`. As with all the tools in the `itertools` module, it returns an iterator which you can consume with the `list` built-in function.

From the documents:

> Used instead of `map()` when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable (the data has been “pre-zipped”). The difference between `map()` and `starmap()` parallels the distinction between `function(a,b)` and `function(*c)`.

Comment: after reading the question again it seems we are all  wrong as the OP wants to  `add(1, 2`), then `add(2, 3)` ... unless that is a mistake by the OP

Comment: `[3, 7 ,11]` is indeed the expected result for my example :)

Comment: lol well they half clarified, the left the *it does `add(1, 2)`, then `add(2, 3)`* but added expected output

Comment: @BinaryFunt: I think now you've clarified the expected output it's clear - I edited the typo which caused the doubt originally.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh I see my mistake. Woops! ajcr has corrected it now

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 foo = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]]

def add(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2

print(map(lambda x: add(x[0], x[1]), foo))
```

Comment: This can be slightly quicker than ajcr's answer

Answer (score 1):

There was another answer with a perfectly valid method (even if not as readable as ajcr's answer), but for some reason it was deleted. I'm going to reproduce it, as it may be useful for certain situations

```
>>> map(add, *zip(*foo))
[3, 7, 11]
```

Comment: I found this super useful to help with passing lists of arguments to tqdm's process_map function.